# Instantiate object and run methods from command line py

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Is there a way I can instantiate an object from the command line and run its methods from the instantiated object separately. Example of what I want to achieve below:

```
import sys

class Calculate(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.xDim = sys.argv[1]
        self.yDim = sys.argv[2]

    def add(self):
        print(self.xDim + self.yDim)

    def multiply(self):
        print(self.xDim * self.yDim)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculate = Calculate()

    calculate.add()
    calculate.multiply()
```

The way I have written this code if I do : python calculate.py 2 2
It will run the two methods add and multiply but I want to be able to create an instance and then do something like: 
python calculate.py 2 2 calculateObject
then do calculateObject.add or calculateObject.multiply

This is needed for a project in php that needs to call the methods separately. I understand I can put add and multiply into different files, instantiate Calculate from within and then run them individually but this will be doing so much. I can consider this if there is no better way.

Comment: From how your question is written it is hard to tell what command line arguments you want to set when calling the program. Something like `python calculate.py 2 2 add` to execute `add`, or `python calculate.py  2 2 add multiple` to execute `add` and then `multiply`?

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to create an object in one invocation of Python from the command line, and then use that object in a later, separate invocation?  That would require your code to save the state of the object in the first run, and then to restore that state on the second.

Comment: If I do python calculate.py 2 2 add and later do pyhon calcuate.py 2 2 multiply it will create the instance of Calculate twice. This is not what I want. I have some heavy lifting done in init and can't afford to do it twice. I want to create the object in the command line and then access those two methods when I want. I don't know if that clarifies? Comment above captures what I want to do.

Comment: There's no real reason to define a class here, but if you do, then `Calculate.__init__` should take the `x` and `y` values as arguments, instead of accessing `sys.argv` directly.

Comment: You can't share instances of a class between runs, unless you save the state (using, for example, `pickle`) to disk in the first run and reload the object on subsequent runs.

Comment: @chepner how can I do that? Is pickle a py module?

Comment: It is, but it sounds like you should instead implement a long-lived server that takes requests, rather than re-running your program each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do so. When you run `python some_script.py` in your terminal, command prompt or through a screen, it will search for and launch Python interpreter as a **new** process. And after the interpreter finishes running the script, it will terminate returning an exit code. All the variables will be cleared from memory after this time. And when you run `python some_script.py` again, a new process is started with prior knowledge of prior runs whatsoever. So if you want the same instance as before, in order to store variable information, you'll need to modify your script to force python to never terminate and keep waiting for new instructions. For example, the python shell will wait for a command because it is listening to user input. Then, in your PHP code, instead of running `python some_script.py` to create a new instance of python, you should be able to invoke the previously running python script which is waiting for some kind of signal. I suggest you to use network sockets because they are highly supported and not that complex to learn and use.